# Prove the divergence of the sequence $ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n+1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking for nice ways of proving the divergence of this sequence

$$x_{n}:=\Biggr(\dfrac{n^2}{n+1}\Bigg)^{n=\infty}$$

Comment: I assume that you mean the limit as $n\to\infty$, not as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Ok I'm wrong I will fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the spirit of Brian M. Scott's answer, observe that:

$$n^2 - 1 < n^2 < n^2 + 2n + 1$$

So we have:

$$\frac{n^2 - 1}{n+1} < \frac{n^2}{n+1} < \frac{n^2 + 2n + 1}{n+1}$$

That is,

$$n-1 < x_n < n+1$$

Since $n-1$ and $n+1$ both (clearly) diverge to infinity as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the same can be said of $x_n$.

(I suppose you only need the left inequality; but at least this lets you see what the behavior of $x_n$ looks like.)

Comment: This is a very nice suggestion

Answer (score 3):

If you use polynomial long division, you can rewrite $\frac{n^2}{n+1}$ as $n-1+\frac{1}{n+1}$. That should make it more clear that the terms keep growing as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $\quad n^2=(n+1)(n-1)+1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{n^2}{n+1}=\frac{\frac{n^2}{n}}{\frac{n}{n}+\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{n}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$
As $n\to\infty$, we diverge.

Comment: How I can forget this !! :)

Comment: You shouldn't....  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just notice that,

> $$ n+1 \sim n \quad \rm as \quad n\to \infty .$$

Answer (score 0):

Given $N$, $\quad\exists\ N'\ \ni\ n > N'
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad n^{2}/\left(n + 1\right) > N$

$$
\mbox{where}\qquad
N'
=
\left\lfloor
{N + \sqrt{\vphantom{\LARGE a}\,N\left(N + 4\right)\,}
 \over
 2}
\right\rfloor\,,
\qquad
N' \in {\mathbb N}
$$